# Laravel Mix, how to pass variable while mixing?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

So I have a JS file that I want to mix and copy and compress using `Laravel mix`; my `webpack.mix.js` file looks like so:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/foo/foo.js', 'public/foo.js');
mix.copy('public/foo.js', 'public/js/foo.js');
mix.version();
```

The thing is that `foo.js` has a variable called `env`, set to `dev` on local envs, and we set it to `app` on production.

Is there a way I can automate this? For example, can I pass the variable according to the `env` while mixing the file and set this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/string-replace

`npm i laravel-mix-string-replace` to install the package

This is how I solved it in mix file:

```
const pixelEnv = process.env.APP_ENV == "local" ? 'dev' : 'app';
mix.js('resources/js/foo/foo.js', 'public/foo.js').stringReplace({
    test: /foo.js/,
    loader: 'string-replace-loader',
    options: {
      search: 'PIXEL_ENV',
      replace: pixelEnv,
    }
  });
```